# I need to merge these two objects together, with different geometry

Tags: modeling, mesh

[image: Image of two separate objects]
Image of two separate objects, the outer shell of the helmet and the neck piece

[image]
Here is another image to represent the difference in the geometry of the two objects

What I am attempting to do is to merge these two objects together so I can give a solid look to this helmet, any ideas of what I can do to accomplish this?

Comment: attach your file here http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/?ref=be-community-add-2 for detail inspection

Comment: Here's the file without the modifier https://www.dropbox.com/s/5ozva12ujnetokq/helmetnomodifier.blend?dl=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Joining both the mesh will not get a better geometry so i deleted the below part. To get a better geometry.

I added a cube and align little bit near the cut or jaw.

I remove doubles (In edit mode -> select all press W key and remove doubles)

With the helmet selected add boolean modifier -> target the cube and apply

With the below faces selected. Extrude and scale down and once again extrude little.

Add smooth shading

Add edge modifier

Add subsurf modifier

If you see some corner edges.Go to edit mode and select the edges and dissolve them.

**This is the result.**

[image]

Due to large size of gif. click [here](http://pasteall.org/pic/index.php?id=119994) to watch the preview and to enlarge the preview click on the preview

[image]

Comment: Beautiful! Thank you so much! Thanks for spending the time on this, do you have another link to download the file? It won't open the file.

Comment: @TylerFurby blend file attach with new link